# Out of memory (allocated 899678208) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: php

Im learning mvc . And trying to code blog . So Im getting error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to 
    allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp2\htdocs\blog_mvc\controllers\Users.php on 
    line 7

I tried to change memory_limit to 512,1024  till 20000. It didnt work . 
I also tried to change to -1 .
And it is M not Mb.
I have not idea what to do . `enter code here`

View/login.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
include("models/db.php");
include("controllers/Users.php");
echo ("memory limit: " . ini_get("memory_limit") . "<br />"); 
echo ("memory usage: " . round(memory_get_usage(true)/1048576,2) . "Mb (" . 
memory_get_usage(true) . " bytes)<br />"); 


if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST["signin"])){

   $object2 = new Users;
   $object2->login($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]); 

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <?php include("includes/inc.style.php")?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row login-form-wrapper">
                    <form  class="login-form" action="" method="post" >
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="username">Логин</label><input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username"></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="password">Пароль</label><input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password"></div>
                <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name ="signin" value="Войти">
                <a href="signupform.php">Dign up</a>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Controllers/Users.php

```
<?php 
class Users extends DB{
    function set($username , $password , $email){
        return $this->insert($username , $password , $email);
    }
    function login($username , $password){
         return $this->login($username , $password );
    }
}
```

Models/db.php

```
<?php 
class DB{
    var $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","Blog");
        if($this->conn->connect_error){
            echo "DB connection error" . $this->conn->connect_error;
        }
        else{
            echo "Connected to db succesfully";
        }
    }

    function login($username , $password){
       echo memory_get_usage();
       $sql="SELECT * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'" ;
        $result=$this->conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION["username"]=$row["username"];
            }
            echo "Success"; //header('Location: post_publication.php');
        } else {
             echo "Не удалось . Ошибка" .$this->conn->error;
        }


        $this->conn->close();
    }   
    function insert($username , $password , $email){
        $result=$this->conn->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','$password','$email','2')");

        if ($result === TRUE) {
            header('Location: login.php?registered=true');
        }
        else{
            $error= "Не удалось . Ошибка" .$this->conn->error;
        }
        $this->conn->close();
    }
    function __destruct(){
        if ($this->conn!==null) { $this->conn = null; }
    }




}
```

Comment: `return $this->login($username , $password );` Is this a recursive infinite call to itself?

Comment: What @Dharman said. You probably wanted `return parent::login($username, $password);` so that you pass the arguments to the parent `DB` class's `login()` method.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It works . I  wanted to call parent's method  and used  $this . Thank you very much .

Comment: Instead of throwing more and more memory at the problem you should take a moment and ask yourself "does my login script _really_ need more than 800MB of RAM?"

Comment: @Sammitch With all due respect, what utopia do you live in?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus back in _my_ day we did all our logins with the bottom 16KB RAM, in the snow, uphill _both_ ways.

Comment: @Sammitch Pfft, RAM is for newbs. I internetted on punch-cards through the postal service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to call a parent in `DB` class from `User`. If your class extends another class then you do not need to redefine that method as long as it is not abstract. Just remove the `login` function from class User.

```
//function login($username , $password){
//     return $this->login($username , $password );
//}
```

or you can call the parent using the following syntax:

```
return parent::login($username, $password);
```

Comment: It works . I  wanted to call parent's method  and used  $this . Thank you very much .  Im trying to fix it all day . I was near to drop learning it=) .  But Im using here child class's login method as controller . And If I will call directly DB method . It isnt mvc , isnt it ? Or I just should rename child's login method to different ?

Answer (score -1):

It's recommended to know how much memory your application is using. That being said, you set the memory utilization limits at run-time like this:

Add one of these lines to your code directly under

```
session_start();


ini_set("memory_limit", "500M"); // Half a gig
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1"); // No memory limit.
```

That should stop the error.

Comment: Please, don't recommend such settings to new PHP users. 500M for PHP script is very generous. Setting no limit on the memory usage would just let PHP eat all available RAM without addressing the core issue.

Comment: I'm not his professor.  He asked how to mitigate the error,  I told him.  He should *definitely* concentrate on using only as much memory as needed and being conservative, but I'm not going to withhold / refuse knowledge from anyone.

Comment: This is a non-answer considering the fact that regardless of how high you raise the limit it does nothing to solve the infinite recursion. Additionally, OP has already tried raising the limit so this fails to even suggest a new idea to try.

Comment: @Justin Jack Thanks .  I actually tried to set -1 . I did it to know if here really  not enough memory or just here infinity loop in code or some error. And it displayed error even when -1 . Now I know it is because recursion .